# IEnumerable Or Enumerable for Enumerating composite objects

Tags: c#

Hello I need some help with the following:

I have a ListView control with many ListViewItems, and each ListViewItem's tag property references a domain object like Customer etc.

when retrieving the collection of selected listviewItems, I would like to pass an `IEnumerable<Customer>` instead of the `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>` to a function to do something with it.

what would be the best way to achieve this with only one loop?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're asking. Could you rephrase?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers() {
    foreach(ListViewItem item in listview)
        yield return (Customer)item.Tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in C# 3 (.NET 3.5) you could use a Linq statement like so:

```
var custs = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(i => i.Tag as Customer);
```

... and of course the same holds true for listView1.SelectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to have to do some kind of transformation, but you can use LINQ to your advantage here.

```
int currentCustomerID = 134;
var listViewItems = customers.Select(c => {
                        ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem();
                        i.Name = c.Name;
                        i.Value = c.CustomerID;
                        i.IsSelected = c.CustomerID == currentCustomerID;
                        i.Tag = c;
                        return i;
                    });
```

This should transform it to the correct collection using only one loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a convert funcion like this

```
public static IEnumerable<TOut> ConvertEnumer<TIn, TOut>(IEnumerable<TIn> src, Func<TIn, TOut> converter) {
   foreach(var itm in src) {
      yield return converter(itm);
   }
}
```

and you would use it:

```
var myCol = ConvertEnumer<ListViewItem, Customer>(listView1.Items, (itm) => itm.Tag as Customer);
```